# How to check for non primitive types in variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, stdvector

I am trying to write a utility function called `print()`, In which If a primitive type is passed, it just prints it and if a `std::vector<int>` of primitive type is passed, it must loop through it and print it. I tried for a `std::vector` of `int` but failed miserably, primarily because I am not sure if this is allowed in c++. It would be much helpful if you could provide some generalized way to do it for vectors of all primitive types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

void print(std::ostream& out) {}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void print(std::ostream& out, T type, Args... args) 
{
    if (std::is_same<T, std::vector<int>>::value) {
        for (auto vector_iterator = type.begin();
            vector_iterator != type.end(); ++vector_iterator) {
            out << (*vector_iterator) << " ";
        }
    } else {
        out << type;
    }
    print(out, args...);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {4,5,6};

    print(std::cout, "bla", 1, 23.0, v);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error that I encountered, if that helps:

```
util.cc: In instantiation of 'void print(std::ostream&, T, Args ...) [with T = const char*; Args = {int, double, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >}; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]':
util.cc:26:36:   required from here
util.cc:11:42: error: request for member 'begin' in 'type', which is of non-class type 'const char*'
   for (auto vector_iterator = type.begin();
                                          ^
util.cc:12:20: error: request for member 'end' in 'type', which is of non-class type 'const char*'
    vector_iterator != type.end(); ++vector_iterator) {
```

Thanks

Comment: This is what `if constexpr` is for. Also, use range-based for loops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can compile C++17, you can use `if constexpr`

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::vector<int>>::value)
```

Before C++17 you have to develop different functions because the `type.begin()`/`type.end()` part is compiled also when `value` is false (also when `T` isn't a `std::vector`).

A possible way to "split" the function is the following

```
template <typename... Args>
void print (std::ostream& out, std::vector<int> const & v, Args... args) 
 {
   for (auto const & i : v)
     out << i << ' ';

   print(out, args...);
 }

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void print (std::ostream& out, T type, Args... args) 
 {
   out << type;

   print(out, args...);
 }
```

or, if you want to intercept different `std::vector` types, you can templatize the type `T` of the `std::vector` and the first function become

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void print (std::ostream& out, std::vector<T> const & v, Args... args) 
 {
   for (auto const & i : v)
     out << i << ' ';

   print(out, args...);
 }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why does `type.begin()` and `type.end()` part still compile. Shouldn't it return `false` in case of mismatch and go the else part?

Comment: @InvincibleImmortal - I think you should search for "c++ if constexpr" for more info; anyway, the point is that -- before the C++17 `if constexpr` -- in a function all is compiled; also when part of the code isn't never used. So you can't write `type.begin()` in a function that can receive also an `int` because `type.begin()` must be compiled also if that line of code is never executed when `type` is an `int`. What do you expect is `if constexpr`.